# Соединение с видеорегистратором по сокету

Tags: java, камера, onvif

Есть видеорегистратор HiQ-7204MH. Он поддерживает протоколы NETIP и ONVIF.

Я программирую свою камеру на Java, которая позволяет получать JPEG-фотографии примерно по 5 фото в секунду.

Есть ли возможность соединить эту камеру, так сказать, "натуральным" способом (средствами Java) при помощи сокета с видеорегистратором, который сможет распознавать эту камеру и получать с неё фотографии, из которых он будет лепить видео?

---

Подскажите, по возможности, какой-нибудь туториал на русском языке по полноценному использованию Onvif или NetIp протоколов. Как камера общается с видеорегистратором? Не профессионал в этой области).

Answer (score 0):

по ONVIF (Open Network Video Interface Forum) попробуй взглянуть на этот проект https://github.com/milg0/onvif-java-lib

по NetIP здесь

https://github.com/fp7-netide/Engine/tree/master/libraries/netip